# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier error

Tags: objective-c, storyboard

i am using this method to return already created cells in storyboards 
 " dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier "
and here is the code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    switch ( indexPath.row )
    {
        case 0:
            CellIdentifier = @"map";
            break;

        case 1:
            CellIdentifier = @"blue";
            break;

        case 2:
            CellIdentifier = @"red";
            break;
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier     forIndexPath: indexPath];


    return cell;
}
```

but i have this error : 
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier map - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

note: i added the identifiers to storyboard as it is here and it dose not work, another important thing is that : this project was running but now it stopped !!!! I download it from appcoda.com

Answer (score 1):

Here what [Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier%3aforIndexPath%3a) says:

> **Important:** You must register a class or nib file using the registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: or registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier: method before calling this method.

…

> Prior to dequeueing any cells, call this method or the registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: method to tell the table view how to create new cells. If a cell of the specified type is not currently in a reuse queue, the table view uses the provided information to create a new cell object automatically.
>
> If you previously registered a class or nib file with the same reuse identifier, the class you specify in the cellClass parameter replaces the old entry. You may specify nil for cellClass if you want to unregister the class from the specified reuse identifier.

So you should register your class like this:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"map"];
}
```

Comment: how can i register nib ? or if i want to use the method
    - (id)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
how can i use it ? i am very new in ios programming .. !!

Comment: i did it and the error gone away but the cells are empty and the application is not like what it has to be !!!

Comment: @user2616686 did you publish your cells with data somewhere? Can you show your cell design and more code?

Comment: you can download the code from here :
http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/
it was working fine i do not know what happens

Comment: I really want to help, but as I can't see your code, I can't see what actually has gone wrong. Maybe you should start following the tutorial from scratch?

Comment: i run the tutorial i send to you many times and it runs perfectly but yesterday it gives me the error i told you before, i cant know what goes wrong now

Comment: did you download the tutorial ? run it .. did it run or do you have the same error i have ?

Comment: you can't Imagine what i did and it works !!! i delete the application from ios simulator and run it again and it works !!